# Is it allowed to use Task.Run in an ASP.NET Core controller?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

Scenario: I have a web service with a "Delete" ASP.NET Core controller action. The implementation consists of two steps: one cheap after which other operations can already no longer see the deleted data, and a long-running second step which performs the actual deletion.

Is it okay to use `Task.Run` for the second operation and never await it and so return to the caller very soon? I know that this task could be lost due to application shutdown, but is it even allowed to offload work to the background using `Task.Run` in ASP.NET Core and never await the resulting task?

Comment: check out background tasks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @Moho Background tasks are used for background services which should run all the time, e.g., a cronjob-like task. They're AFAIK not intended for one-off work from controllers.

Comment: How long are we talking about? 10 seconds? 1 hour? a day?

Comment: About two to five minutes. But I'm interested in the question in theory as well.

Comment: @DR You’re wrong. Check the [Queued background tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks) section. You can also use some background task framework (such as Hangfire) to support scalability of background tasks and retries upon server stops and errors.

Comment: what @AlexSkalozub said; the queue example is well suited for your situation

Comment: Just remember not to use anything related to the controller or http request itself, because service scope associated with the current request will be gone upon background task execution.

Comment: OK, in that case I will use queued background tasks. Thank you. Still, I'm theoretically interested in the question: is it allowed to just Task.Run() in a controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know that this task could be lost due to application shutdown, but is it even allowed to offload work to the background using Task.Run in ASP.NET Core and never await the resulting task?

Oh, sure, nothing will prevent this. .NET and ASP.NET allow you to use `Task.Run`, and the response will be returned to the user without delay (assuming you ignore the task returned from `Task.Run`).

> Is it okay to use Task.Run for the second operation and never await it and so return to the caller very soon?

You say that you're aware that the task could be lost in an app shutdown. And that's true; so it is entirely possible that the second deletion may never happen, and there will be no error or log message informing you of the fact. Furthermore, since the task is ignored, there will be no notification if that task fails, so if there's something wrong with the deletion code, no logs or anything will notify you of regular failures. If you're OK with that, then using fire-and-forget is fine.

On ASP.NET Core, you don't even need `Task.Run`; you can just call the (asynchronous) method that does the second delete operation and then ignore the task instead of `await`ing it.

Simply ignoring tasks will work (with or without `Task.Run`), but this does have the negative side effect that ASP.NET isn't aware of the offloaded work *at all*. So I would recommend [registering the task and having something delay the app shutdown until the tasks have a chance to complete](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/805). With registration, it is still possible to lose tasks, but registering them reduces the chance of losing tasks.